# Right way to examine if a set is a linear independent of $\mathcal L(V,W)$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

The Exercise 2.4.21 is in the textbook linear algebra 4th edition by Stephen H. Friedberg Arnold J. Insel Lawrence E. Spence
[image]

Find the set is linear independent:
Let $$\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n a_i{_j}T_i{_j} = 0(zero\ transformation)$$
The goal is that every coefficient $a_i{_j}$ is $0$.

Choose an arbitrary element of $\beta\ ,\ v_k$ to the zero transforamtion:
$$\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n a_i{_j}T_i{_j}(v_k) = 0$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^m a_i{_k}w_i = 0$$
$$a_1{_k}w_1+a_2{_k}w_2+...+a_m{_k}w_m = 0$$
$\gamma$ is a basis, $a_1{_k}...a_m{_k}$ are all zero.

Because $k$ is arbitrary, so the whole coefficients $a_i{_j}$ are all zero, so $T_i{_j}$ is linear indepent.

Is this a legitimate way to say the set is linear independent?

I've also looked for some solutions which chooses  $v\ \epsilon\ V $ to put into the formation, but I don't understand why it can conclude $a_i{_j}a_j$ is zero?
I can only see $\sum_{j=1}^n a_i{_j}a_j$ is zero at most:

[image]

Comment: Find the matrix representation of $T_{ij}$ wrt those bases. The space of matrices  has an obvious basis of matrices with a $1$ in a certain location and $0$'s elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is good. Better, in fact, than the provided solution, in my opinion.

The provided solution doesn't articulate it very well, but you have to remember that the $a_i$s can be essentially chosen however we want. The calculation is for an arbitrary $v \in V$, and we can consider this equality for any $v$ we wish. We know that $\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} a_j = 0$ for all $i$, but also for any choice of $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ we want.

If we want to show that $a_{ik}$ is $0$ specifically (for some fixed $k$), then the sensible choice would be $a_j = 0$ for $j \neq k$ and $a_k = 1$. Of course, this corresponds to $v = v_k$, which is precisely what you (sensibly) decided to evaluate with $T_{ij}$. So, essentially, if you fill in the missing/suppressed steps, the given solution is valid because it's your proof, but argued less convincingly and efficiently.

(Or maybe I'm being slightly harsh, and they use the steps later when proving the proposed basis is spanning. I can't tell from the excerpt.)

Comment: $a_i$s? or $a_j$s  you mean?

Comment: They are the same $a$'s. I mean $a_1, \ldots, a_n$.